# CSS- cant align text in line

Tags: html, css, tags, element

```css
.hiphop{
 
 width: 900px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 5px 10px 10px;
 overflow: auto;
}

.hiphop .hartist{
word-spacing: 5cm;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.hiphop .halbum{
 word-spacing: 5cm;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class=hiphop>
 <h4>HIPHOP</h4>
 <p class="hartist"> 
  <a href="#">Artist</a> 
  <a href="#">Discussion</a>
  <a href="#">Comments</a>
  <a href="#">Latest</a>
 </p>

<p class="halbum">
 <a href="#">Album</a>
 <a  href="#">Discussion</a>
 <a  href="#">Comments</a>
 <a  href="#">Latest</a>
</p>

</div>
```

When I run this code the part for Album does not align like how it does with artist. Not really sure why

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/524jo8kt/1/

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#navigation {
     background-color: #fff;
     height:100px;
     position: relative;
     border:3px solid red;
     padding:4px;
}
li{
margin: 0;
width:20%;

text-align:center;
height:25px;
     padding: 0;
     margin:2px;
     background-color:silver;
     border: 0;
     list-style: none;
     line-height: 1;
     display: inline;
     position: relative;
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     float: left;}
     .
</style>
<body>

<div id="navigation">
 <ul class="navbar1">
  <li><a href="#">Artist</a> </li>                            
  <li> <a href="#">Discussion</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Comments</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Latest</a></li>
   </ul>
      
        
        <br>
 <ul class="navbar2">            
  <li><a href="#">Album</a> </li>                              
  <li><a href="#">Discussion</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Comments</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Latest</a></li>
   </ul>
      </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: He doesn't need background and centering text, just width and float.

Comment: But its not look proper